# Cómo usar un modelo con transfer learning usando @tensorflow/tfjs-node

Tags: tensorflow, inteligencia-artificial, keras

Estoy intentando usar un módelo entrenado con transferencia de aprendizaje usando la librería de `@tensorflow/tfjs-node` y me encuentro con un problema al no poder usar el modelo exportado ya que me pide la capa de el módelo pre entrenado pero no es posible cargar adecuadamente el módelo aquí dejo el código.

````
modelo = keras.Sequential([
hub.KerasLayer(url, input_shape=(224,224,3), trainable=False),
keras.layers.Dense(100, activation="relu"),
keras.layers.Dense(2, activation="softmax"),
])
...
modelo.save(('./modelos/'+modelName+'/keras/modelo.h5'))
score = modelo.evaluate(data_test)
tfjs.converters.save_keras_model(modelo, ('./modelos/'+modelName+'/tfjs'))```
y tengo este error

[ERROR] 00:48:28 Error: Unknown layer: KerasLayer. This may be due to one of the following reasons:
1. The layer is defined in Python, in which case it needs to be ported to TensorFlow.js or your JavaScript code.
2. The custom layer is defined in JavaScript, but is not registered properly with tf.serialization.registerClass().

que debo de hacer para que funcione, lo estoy haciendo así.

`model = await tf.loadLayersModel(`file://./src/MLModels/tfjs/model.json`);`
y con
`model = await tf.loadGraphModel(`file://./src/MLModels/tfjs/model.json`);`
obtengo el error

[ERROR] 01:03:17 TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'producer')
en internet no encuentro cómo se soluciona esto.

este es el código
````

```
import { LoadOptions } from '@tensorflow/tfjs-core/dist/io/types';
import * as tf from '@tensorflow/tfjs-node';
import { LayersModel,Shape, loadGraphModel, Tensor, Tensor4D } from '@tensorflow/tfjs-node';

class KerasLayer extends tf.layers.Layer {
  constructor(config?: any) {
    super(config);
  }

  build(inputShape: Shape | Shape[]): void {
  }

  call(inputs: Tensor | Tensor[], kwargs?: any): Tensor | Tensor[] | Tensor4D {
    return super.call(inputs, kwargs) as Tensor4D;
  }

  static get className(): string {
    return 'KerasLayer';
  }
}

tf.serialization.registerClass(KerasLayer);

let model: any | null = null;

export const loadModel = async (): Promise<LayersModel > => {
  if (!model) {
    try {
      const customLayer = new KerasLayer({}); 
      const modelUrl = 'https://tfhub.dev/google/tf2-preview/mobilenet_v2/feature_vector/4';

      model = await loadGraphModel(modelUrl, { customObjects: { 'KerasLayer': customLayer } } as LoadOptions)  ;
      console.log("Modelo cargado exitosamente");
      model = model as LayersModel;
      return model; 
    } catch (error: any) {
      console.error("Error al cargar el modelo:", error.message);
      return model;
    }
  } else {
    return model;
  }
};

loadModel();

export default {
  loadModel,
};
```

Gracias por la ayuda, en este [issue](https://github.com/tensorflow/tfjs/issues/3786) encontrarán una explicación más espeficifica de mi problema.